# Pandas is looping twice when applying a function on a csv row python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv document with a column called "IP Address" and three other columns with random data in it. My goal is to loop through the IP Address column and run bulkfunc on each IP Address, outputting the contents to a text file.

I have panda properly accessing the data, but for some reason it loops through twice, thus, since I have 3 IP addresses in the CSV, I get 6 output files.

```
def bulkcsv():
  df = pd.read_csv(('csvfiles/' + inputfile), dtype=str, usecols=['IP Address'])
  #for row in df:
  df.applymap(bulkfunc)
```

Here's my bulkfunc function:

```
def bulkfunc(x):
  global f
  global ip
  ip = x
  f = open('results/%s' % ip + "_" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d@%H%M") + '.txt', 'a')
  print "Static Information: "
  f.write("Static Information: ")
  print "-" * 30
  f.write("-" * 30)
  parsenetworkcsv(ip)
  ping(ip)
  nmaprun(ip, "-sV")
  print "The output is complete."
  f.write("-" * 30)
  f.write("created by OP")
  f.close()
```

Heres the csv:

```
IP Address  random crap   hiya    intwer
10.90.11.252    dawd4     4654    14512
10.90.11.253    144         0
10.90.11.254    203
```

Comment: First of all, I do not believe you need the for loop, the df.applymap should be enough. Please see the pandas documentation at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html. See if this solves the issue. Also, to suggest a solution, a sample of your input data is well appreciated.

Comment: I got rid of the loop and it still loops twice.

Comment: But thank you for the suggestions, I added them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, this should solve the issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime

def bulkcsv():
  inputfile = 'inp.csv'
  df = pd.read_csv(('csvfiles/' + inputfile), dtype=str, usecols=['IP Address'])
  #print df
  #for row in df:
  #print df['IP Address'].shape
  df['IP Address'].map(bulkfunc)

def bulkfunc(x):
  global f
  global ip
  ip = x
  f = open('results/%s' % ip + "_" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d@%H%M%S") + '.txt', 'a')
  print "Static Information: "
  f.write("Static Information: ")
  print "-" * 30
  f.write("-" * 30)
  parsenetworkcsv(ip)
  ping(ip)
  nmaprun(ip, "-sV")
  print "The output is complete."
  f.write("-" * 30)
  f.write("created by OP")
  f.close()
  time.sleep(1)

bulkcsv()
```

**Output:**

```
     IP Address
0  10.90.11.252
1  10.90.11.253
2  10.90.11.254
(3L,)
Static Information:
------------------------------
The output is complete.
Static Information:
------------------------------
The output is complete.
Static Information:
------------------------------
The output is complete.
```

The problem seems to be because of pd.read_csv. In your code, you had read it as a DataFrame. The shape of this is (3L,1), because of which the applymap loops twice (index 0 and 1). But, when we use as a Series, as you have only one column, the map does the job for you. You can also use, apply function of the DataFrame. I believe applymap works well for More than 1 dimension DataFrame, else it should be treated as series.

I believe this can possibly a bug or change request for Pandas. You can try that route.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Much appreciated!